# How to stabilize series of jpgs for animated gif?

Tags: animation, gif, jpg

There is this series of jpegs that I want to turn into an animated gif.  That's easy enough, but the subject jumps around as the people in the image shift.  How can I stabilize the subjects?  I know there is a thing called image stabilization for video, but can you do it for still images?  How can I chieve this?

Comment: It's possible to auto-align images in Photoshop. But if it's not too many images you could do it manually. Which software do you have?

Comment: If you have a video program that has it, pull the images as a video sequence, stabilize it and then turn the video into animated gif. I will try to post this as an answer later with a specific free program.

Comment: I found a tutorial for doing this with Hugin: https://imgur.com/gallery/3qfWQ  But I can't find any way to export the images back to single files, nor to create an animated gif.

Comment: ffmpeg is a very powerful command line tool, that can as well do gif <-> single frame files.